# Exception when notification is received

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an Android app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I am testing the app in 2 real devices:

Device 1: Android 7.0, API 24

Device 2: Android 8.1.0, API 27

This is my MyFirebaseMessaging:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        String sented = remoteMessage.getData().get("sented");
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");

        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String currentUser = preferences.getString("currentuser", "none");

        Log.d("current user ","currentuser "+currentUser);

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (firebaseUser != null && sented.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
            if (!currentUser.equals(user)) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    sendOreoNotification(remoteMessage);
                } else {
                    sendNotification(remoteMessage);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendOreoNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title, body, pendingIntent,
                defaultSound, icon);

        int i = 0;
        if (j > 0){
            i = j;
        }

        oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());

    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int i = 0;
        if (j > 0){
            i = j;
        }

        noti.notify(i, builder.build());
    }
}
```

My issue is that the notifications are received on device 2, but on device 1 I am getting an exception at line:

```
 private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
        String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
  EXCEPTION HERE ===>      int j = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("userid", user);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager noti = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int i = 0;
        if (j > 0){
            i = j;
        }

        noti.notify(i, builder.build());
    }
```

Exception output:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "5517300173"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:524)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
        at com.mpidesarrollo.chatapp.Notifications.MyFirebaseMessaging.sendNotification(MyFirebaseMessaging.java:86)
```

Comment: Are you asking why you're getting that particular value? Or are you asking why it's throwing the `NumberFormatException`? If it's the latter, 5,517,300,173 is larger than an `Integer`/`int` can hold, which is 2,147,483,647.

Comment: @MikeM., I have taken this code example from a tutorial, but you are right. How could I solve that issue?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use that value for the `PendingIntent`'s request code, or the `Notification`'s ID. Those are simply used to determine unique instances of those things within your app. Those values don't need to be directly tied to a Firebase value, so you could just provide your own (valid) value, however you'd like to figure that.

Comment: @MikeM.  thank you. I am testing with a random integer and works fine.